# Play .mp4 videos using HTML5

Tags: html, video, playback

How can I play .mp4 videos using HTML5 using the video tag? Does chrome support HTML5 with .mp4 videos?

Answer (score 0):

Safari can play h264 encoded mp4 videos,  Chrome nolonger supports them,  Firefox never did.  If you pick [Google's WebM format](http://www.webmproject.org/),  it will work in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Actually Chrome still support MP4 but is planning to drop support for it. It just hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 0):

chrome does support MP4 video with H.264 video codec, But it can only play video with "Baseline profile" of H.264.

Answer (score 0):

The state of media currently with browsers is that you will likely not find a format that works with all browsers, so you will need to encode your video/audio in at least 2 or 3 different formats. There is a nice jQuery plugin called jPlayer that I would heartily recommend if you're going to start out with HTML5 media. The documentation is pretty good and it will really help you work with different browsers. http://jplayer.org/.